# [i18n]Load Resource Bundle out of classpath

Tags: java, internationalization, resourcebundle

I am trying to load a `.properties` file from some folder other than the classpath of my project for my `ResourceBundle` loading for internationalization. I have a structure like this:

```
MyProject
    |
     - src
       |
        -com
         |
          -company
             |
              -UI
              -launcher
              -resources
                   |
                    -i18n.properties
                    -i18n_en_US.properties
                    -i18n_es_ES.properties
                    -i18n_zh_CN.properties
```

Obviously, it's clearer than putting all `i18n` files under the same level as `src` folder. So, how can I load them? More precisely, in the line of loading my resource bundle, how shall I put the `baseName` part?

```
bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(baseName,localeInSettings);
```

I have seen answers around, but not so clear. As I find something, I come to share it with all and make it clearer.

Comment: The point is: "src" location doesn't matter. The question is: where do you copy it when building the thing that you deploy?

Comment: You mean if I pack all classes into a jar, the location can change due to jar files internal structure changes? So I guess by default it shouldn't change, should it? Must avoid it..

Answer (score 0):

It's still in the classpath. Just not in the default package. So the base name should be

```
com.company.resources.i18n
```

Answer (score 0):

As the experiments proved, the both forms work:

```
com/WindThunderStudio/resources/i18n
```

And,

```
com.WindThunderStudio.resources.i18n
```

First, it is different from loading normal properties files, you don't note your absolute path with "/" before complete path.

Second, the first form works as we all expected, because baseName expected "full qualified names", that is, path with ".". As the second form, we can quote from JavaDoc page of [`ResourceBundle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html):

> Note:The baseName argument should be a fully qualified class name. However, for compatibility with earlier versions, Sun's Java SE Runtime Environments do not verify this, and so it is possible to access PropertyResourceBundles by specifying a path name (using "/") instead of a fully qualified class name (using ".").